# How can I ensure I have a better magicka regeneration rate during combat?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My magicka depletes quite fast during fights (playing full mage).
Are there any suggestions you can give me?
Is there any talent to increase magicka regeneration rate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From this guide:  [Mage Guide](http://www.gamingreality.com/2011/11/skyrim-mage-guide.html)

It seems the best way is to reduce the spell cost, rather than increase the regeneration rate.

Copied from the guide:

> Now for the unlimited mana...
>
> 1. Find an item that 'reduces the mana cost of destruction spells.
> 2. Disenchant to learn the "Fortify destruction" spell.
> 3. Get your enchanting skill up into the 40+ range.
> 4. Get enchanting perks that make it 20/40/60/80/100 more effective.
> 5. Get the 'insightful' 'corpus' and 'extra effect' perks as you can.
> 6. Get your hands on 3 Grand soul gems with Grand souls.
> 7. Get your hands on a ring, necklace, and circlet you like.
> 8. Apply the 'fortify destruction' enchant to all three, and equip them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are perks for magicka regeneration (see in restoration at least).

There are also items that increase X% of magicka regeneration.

But the higher the cost of the spell you use, the faster magicka depletes. So try to get the cast for half cost perks too, and eventually, reduce cast cost upgrades on your gear.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that magicka regeneration improvements do not affect your in combat regeneration.

Magicka regeneration out of combat is set to give you 3% of your total magicka per second, but while in combat that drops down to 33% of the normal regeneration rate, meaning only 1 percent of your total magicka is regenerated per second. This does not seem to factor in any magicka regeneration gear when in combat.

Over at [Skyrim Nexus](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/) they have mod files for adjusting your in combat regeneration. Personally I'd just settle for somehow applying your magicka regeneration gear to the in combat regeneration rate, but that doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I'm sure someone will mod it soon.

Comment: I see.. or should I go for enchanting and decrease the cost of destruction spells?

Comment: This is wrong. Magicka regen does work in combat.

Answer (score 2):

You can wear the Arch-Mage's robes after completing the quest for Winterhold, you can wear Morokei (both give plus 100% regeneration, Savos Aren's Amulet gives you 50+ magika, the Gaulder Amulet/ 1 of 3 of the Gualder Amulet fragments will give you 30+ magika, a Mage's circlet that Savos Aren will give you in one of the quests you do for the College, random loot and randomly available in shop keepers inventory, and you can also enchant your own things.

Also, all of the god's necklaces will give you boosts to whatever and you can also try getting married because your wedding ring will give you a -12% cost of Restoration spells. These are all the things that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Get you some ELSWEYR FONDUE to go with your other solutions, which you can make at a cooking pot with MOON SUGAR, ALE, & ELDAR CHEESE WHEEL.

It grants:

25% Magicka Regen Rate & 100 Magicka for 720 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If it's true that MReg items (other than Ring of Erudite) don't apply during combat, and base MReg rates are 3%/1% of your total Magicka per second, it would stand to reason that, between raising Magicka and raising MReg, you would want to raise your total Magicka with item enchantments when anticipating combat.

THAT SAID, the clearest game-changer is going to be cost reduction enchants, because there is no cap, making spells of any school entirely free with the right gear, either chest/head/ring/neck at 25% each or Archmage's Robes (15%) and head/ring/neck at at least 29% each (Fortify Enchanting potions of +16% or higher should get you from 25% to there. IIRC, Fortify Enchant potions functionally cap at 29% or 31% ). LASTLY, if you get your capped Fortify Alch potions, fully maxed Enchanting w/all relevant perks, the Ahzidal's Genius bonus from wearing 4 pieces of his gear to the enchanting table (Kolbjorn Barrow on Solstheim), and Seeker of Sorcery from the Black Book in white Ridge Barrow (Solstheim, as well), you can achieve Cost Reduction bonuses of up to 34%, which is enough to get full cost reduction out of ONLY THREE ITEMS, so if you have the Dragonborn DLC, DON'T ENCHANT THE JAGGED CROWN until you're fully prepared to bring it up to the 34% it DESERVES :D

Stackable Headear Sidenote: If you're Stacking Two Pieces Of Headgear (Circlet + Penitus Oculatus Helmet/Falmer Helmet/Jagged Crown) you can really free up a lot of extra slots for defensive/sneaky/H2H enchants. I really can't see myself wearing anything but the Jagged Crown into battle, but I'll wear an ugly hat/circlet to the Alchemy Table if it makes the potions fortifying my Destruction Damage 34% stronger. And really, wait on cost-reduction-enchanting the unique Jagged Crown until you've hit 34% capability because it just sucks SOOOOOO much to have pulled the trigger at 25% when all you needed was a black book, a beefy potion, and 4 pieces of a mad genius' armor to use it as your endgame headgear.

Rate-of-Fire Sidenote: The less your spells cost as a percentage of your total magicka, the FASTER you can cast them, so hitting that 100% cost reduction NOT ONLY gives your six-shooter infinite bullets, it increases your rate of fire, boosting your DPS significantly. So you can fireball your enemies to Oblivion (and Vigilance to Sovngard) THAT MUCH FASTER!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a high level enchanter, you can create a ring or necklace with a regeneration rate as well. Remember to use fortify enchantment potions. I got mine up to 62%.

Answer (score 0):

WRITE IN SKYRIM (1-3 STEPS or more from 0.1 to 0.9)

`~ (CONSOLE)`
`player.modav magickarate -0.9 (ENTER)`  [ -2 speed magick ]
`player.modav magickarate -0.9 (ENTER)`  [ -3 speed magick ]
`player.modav magickarate -0.9 (ENTER)`  [ -10 speed magick ]
`~ (CONSOLE)`

P.S. 4 STEP WAS 0 SPEED MAGICK REGEN

p.s ~

`set timescale to 2`      [ time 2/1 real ]
`enablefasttravel 0`     [no fast travel  1 - on]
`player.additem f 1000`  [1000gold or more]

Answer (score 0):

While your base magicka regeneration rate is 3% of your base magicka/second and during combat it is 1% of your base magicka/second, these 2 values CAN be changed, but by only ONE item in the game: The Ring of the Erudite (available ONLY with the Dawnguard DLC and ONLY if you side with Hokar (Vampires) at the end of the "Bloodlines" quest). What is 100% unique about this ring is that it INCREASES YOUR BASE MAGICKA REGENERATION RATE by 2% and adds 100 magicka. So, while wearing The Ring of the Erudite, your base magicka regeneration rate outside of combat will be 5% and your base magicka regeneration during combat will be 3% - a whopping 66% increase! Once worn, all fortify magicka regeneration enchantments will use these new base magicka regeneration rates in their calculations, rather than the standard 3%/1%. base magicka regeneration rate
Even if you HATE playing as a vampire, it is worth playing as one for a little while in order to obtain The Ring of the Erudite (obtained during "The Rings of Blood Magic" quest)  it will increase your overall magicka regeneration significantly more than ANY OTHER item in Elder Scrolls V.

Comment: TIL, This is a useful thing to know, unless one is looking at the UESP/Wiki for this item.

Answer (score -1):

Long time not played Skyrim, but I used to play full mage too, As Far as I remember I used to enchant all my armor and weapons with reduced cost of the mana. So with 4 items each with a reduction of 25% you have the reduction of cost to 100%. with that I literally spammed any single spell on any enemy from the distance and the enemy dies in seconds. Even with -Spoiler alert- any master destruction spell active.
So yes there's a way, but you will not achieve it in the first levels, this is mid-late game completion.

Answer (score -2):

Finish the Winterhold quests. The Mask of Moreki and Archmage Robes combined with Savos Aren's Amulet should more than fulfill your magicka regeneration requirements.

It is almost like you don't even need to watch your magicka usage after you have these items. These coupled with the 60 second highborn power will give you too much magicka; there is no way you could even use it all.

Comment: btw, these items give you a combined 200% regen rate, +100 magica, and 15% lower spell costs in all schools of magic

Comment: Sorry mate but in my experience (full mage 39 level) this is not enough, because during combat the regen rate is lowered a lot and when you play 'glass cannon' style the game changer is the spell reduction cost, because you'll have to dual cast a lot of offensive spells in a very short amount of time.